# Remove First name & last name field from firebase auth - email

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I am using firebase auth for my website i have enabled Google, facebook & Email based auth everything works fine, But when using Email login Users are required to enter Firstname But i don't need these details and want to keep the user login / signup process short

Question : Can we remove the First & Lastname fields from firebase auth email

[image: e]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web#configure-email-provider) it seems you can toggle the requirement to enter a name with `requireDisplayName`.

From that link comes this example:

```
ui.start('#firebaseui-auth-container', {
  signInOptions: [
    {
      provider: firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.PROVIDER_ID,
      requireDisplayName: false
    }
  ]
});
```